# Set variable equal to exact column and row

Tags: mysql, sql, function

This is quite a newbie question, but I cannot find anything specific to my issue elsewhere. I'm looking for a very specific syntax.

Let's say I have a database table with 3 columns, `id`, `user`, and `active`.

Now there's a bit more to this story, but in the end I need to store the value in `user` on the row with a certain `id` into a variable for later use.

The MySQL documentation does an okay job of explaining how to create procedures and variables, but all its examples just use variables to hold a constant value, nothing from the actual database.

Basically, here's what I'm looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure (id INT UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
        DECLARE @username VARCHAR(8);
        -- set username equal to user column of row with this id in MyTable

        UPDATE MyTable SET ... WHERE user=@username;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want:

```
SELECT @username = user 
FROM MyTable
WHERE id = @id;
```